# Programmatically scraping a response header within R

Tags: r, curl, httr

I am trying to access the highlighted **response header: location** text in the screenshot below using only R and its curl-based webscraping libraries.  one can easily get to this point in any web browser by visiting http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/WVSDocumentationWVL.jsp, clicking on the download for any of the data files, and filling out the agreement form.  The download begins automatically in a web browser.

[image]

I believe that the only way to obtain a valid cookie is with `library(curlconverter)` (see [How to download a file behind a semi-broken javascript asp function with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156180/how-to-download-a-file-behind-a-semi-broken-javascript-asp-function-with-r)) but that answer does not appear to be enough to programmatically determine the *http url* of the file, only to download the zipped file once it's already known.

I've pasted some code below with different httr and curlconverter code that I've played around with, but I'm missing something here.  Again, the only goal is to programmatically determine the highlighted text entirely within R (cross-platform).

```
library(curlconverter)
library(httr)

browserPOST <-
    "curl 'http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/AJDownload.jsp'
    -H 'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
    -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate'
    -H 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8'
    -H 'Cache-Control:max-age=0'
    --compressed -H 'Connection:keep-alive'
    -H 'Content-Length:188'
    -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    -H 'Cookie:ASPSESSIONIDCASQAACD=IBLGBFOAEHFILMMJJCFEOEMI; JSESSIONID=50DABDEDD0B2FC370C415B4BD1855260; __atuvc=13%7C45; __atuvs=58224f37d312c42400c'
    -H 'Host:www.worldvaluessurvey.org'
    -H 'Origin:http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org'
    -H 'Referer:http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/AJDownloadLicense.jsp'
    -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1'
    -H 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'"

form_data <-
    list( 
        ulthost = "WVS" ,
        CMSID = "" ,
        LITITLE = "" ,
        LINOMBRE = "fas" ,
        LIEMPRESA = "asf" ,
        LIEMAIL = "asdf" ,
        LIPROJECT = "asfd" ,
        LIUSE = "1" ,
        LIPURPOSE = "asdf" ,
        LIAGREE = "1" ,
        DOID = "3996" ,
        CndWAVE = "-1" ,
        SAID = "-1" ,
        AJArchive = "WVS Data Archive" ,
        EdFunction = "" ,
        DOP = "" 
    )   



getDATA <- (straighten(browserPOST) %>% make_req)[[1]]()

a <- VERB(verb = "POST", url = "http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/AJDownload.jsp", 
    httr::add_headers(Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", 
        `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate", `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
        `Cache-Control` = "max-age=0", Connection = "keep-alive", 
        `Content-Length` = "188", Host = "www.worldvaluessurvey.org", 
        Origin = "http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org", Referer = "http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/AJDownloadLicense.jsp", 
        `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` = "1", `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"), 
    httr::set_cookies(`Cookie:ASPSESSIONIDCASQAACD` = "IBLGBFOAEHFILMMJJCFEOEMI", 
        JSESSIONID = "50DABDEDD0B2FC370C415B4BD1855260", `__atuvc` = "13%7C45", 
        `__atuvs` = "58224f37d312c42400c"), encode = "form",body=form_data)
```

Comment: I've added capitalization and punctuation to your question. Please consider doing this yourself in the future as we try to maintain good quality standards for the dozens to thousands of people who may be reading this over time.

Comment: One issue here is that the links are embedded in an iframe that is embedded in another iframe. Scraping those aren't easy, to put it mildly.

Comment: Voting as unclear as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498277/programmatically-scraping-a-response-header-within-r#comment68826373_40786535

Comment: Consider rephrasing the question if you really want to get an answer you want. It's impossible to answer a question asking god-knows-what, and there are no telepathists here.

Comment: @Anthony - Just making sure I understand what you want. Do you want to create an R script to download the files, without the user having to enter the registration data manually? Correct? If that is your goal, then you can do that with the RSelenium package. (Headless Browser)

Comment: @Technophobe01 no, i just want to capture the highlighted url entirely with R (cross-platform and without external installs).  the linked SO question already downloads properly if the url is known.  thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a nice challenge!

The problem is not related to R language. We'll have the same result in any language if we just try to post some data to the download script. We have to deal with some kind of security “pattern” here. The site restricts users from retrieving the files urls and it asks them to fill forms with data in order to provide those links. If a browser can retrieve these links, then we can too by writing the proper HTTP calls. Thing is, we need to know exactly which calls we have to make. In order to find that, we need to see the individual calls the site does whenever someone clicks to download. Here is what I found a few calls before a successful `302 AJDownload.jsp` `POST` call:

[image: Http requests]

We can see it clearly, if we look at the `AJDocumentation.jsp` source, it makes these calls by using jQuery `$.get`:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", function (response) {
    var geodatos=encodeURIComponent(response.ip+"\t"+response.country+"\t"+response.postal+"\t"+
    response.loc+"\t"+response.region+"\t"+response.city+"\t"+
    response.org);

    $.get("jdsStatJD.jsp?ID="+geodatos+
        "&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.worldvaluessurvey.org%2FAJDocumentation.jsp&referer=null&cms=Documentation",
        function (resp2) {
    });
}, "jsonp");
```

Then, a few calls below, we can see the successful `POST /AJDownload.jsp` with status `302 Moved Temporarily` and with the wanted `Location` in its response headers:

[image: Http requests]

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/wvsdc/CO00001/F00003724-WVS_Longitudinal_1981-2014_stata_dta_v_2015_04_18.zip
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 16:24:37 GMT
```

So, this is the security mechanism of this site. It uses [ipinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io) to store visitor informations about their IP, Location and even the ISP organization, just before the user is about to initiate a download by clicking on a link. The script which receives these data, is the `/jdsStatJD.jsp`. I haven’t used ipinfo.io, nor their API key for this service (have it hidden on my screenshots) and instead I created a dummy valid sequence of data, just to validate the request. The post form data for the “protected” files are not require at all. It is possible to download the files without posting these data.

Also, the `curlconverter` library is not required. All we have to do, is simple `GET` and `POST` requests by using `httr` library. One important part I want to point out, is that in order to prevent `httr` `POST` function from following the `Location` header received with `302` status at our last call, we need to use the config setting `config(followlocation = FALSE)` which of course will prevent it from following the `Location` and let us fetch the `Location` from the headers.

**OUTPUT**

My R script can be run from the command line and it can accept `DOID` numeric values for parameters to get the file needed. For example, if we want to get the link for the file `WVS_Longitudinal_1981-2014_stata_dta_v_2015_04_18`, then we have to add its `DOID` (*which is 3724*) to the end of our script when calling it using the `Rscript` command:

```
Rscript wvs_fetch_downloads.r 3724
[1] "http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/wvsdc/CO00001/F00003724-WVS_Longitudinal_1981-2014_stata_dta_v_2015_04_18.zip"
```

I have created an R function to get each file location you want by just passing the `DOID`:

```
getFileById <- function(fileId)
```

You can remove the command line argument parsing and use the function by passing the `DOID` directly:

```
#args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
#if(length(args) == 0) {
#   print("No file id specified. Use './script.r ####'.")
#   quit("no")
#}

#fileId <- args[1]
fileId <- "3724"

# DOID=3843 : WVS_EVS_Integrated_Dictionary_Codebook v_2014_09_22 (Excel)
# DOID=3844 : WVS_Values Surveys Integrated Dictionary_TimeSeries_v_2014-04-25 (Excel)
# DOID=3725 : WVS_Longitudinal_1981-2014_rdata_v_2015_04_18
# DOID=3996 : WVS_Longitudinal_1981-2014_sas_v_2015_04_18
# DOID=3723 : WVS_Longitudinal_1981-2014_spss_v_2015_04_18
# DOID=3724 : WVS_Longitudinal_1981-2014_stata_dta_v_2015_04_18

getFileById(fileId)
```

**Final R working script**

```
library(httr)

getFileById <- function(fileId) {
    response <- GET(
        url = "http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/AJDocumentation.jsp?CndWAVE=-1", 
        add_headers(
            `Accept` = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", 
            `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate",
            `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
            `Cache-Control` = "max-age=0",
            `Connection` = "keep-alive", 
            `Host` = "www.worldvaluessurvey.org", 
            `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0",
            `Content-type` = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            `Referer` = "http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/AJDownloadLicense.jsp", 
            `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` = "1"))

    set_cookie <- headers(response)$`set-cookie`
    cookies <- strsplit(set_cookie, ';')
    cookie <- cookies[[1]][1]

    response <- GET(
        url = "http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/jdsStatJD.jsp?ID=2.72.48.149%09IT%09undefined%0941.8902%2C12.4923%09Lazio%09Roma%09Orange%20SA%20Telecommunications%20Corporation&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.worldvaluessurvey.org%2FAJDocumentation.jsp&referer=null&cms=Documentation", 
        add_headers(
            `Accept` = "*/*", 
            `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate",
            `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
            `Cache-Control` = "max-age=0",
            `Connection` = "keep-alive", 
            `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest",
            `Host` = "www.worldvaluessurvey.org", 
            `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0",
            `Content-type` = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            `Referer` = "http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/AJDocumentation.jsp?CndWAVE=-1",
            `Cookie` = cookie))

    post_data <- list( 
        ulthost = "WVS",
        CMSID = "",
        CndWAVE = "-1",
        SAID = "-1",
        DOID = fileId,
        AJArchive = "WVS Data Archive",
        EdFunction = "",
        DOP = "",
        PUB = "")  

    response <- POST(
        url = "http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/AJDownload.jsp", 
        config(followlocation = FALSE),
        add_headers(
            `Accept` = "*/*", 
            `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate",
            `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
            `Cache-Control` = "max-age=0",
            `Connection` = "keep-alive",
            `Host` = "www.worldvaluessurvey.org",
            `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0",
            `Content-type` = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            `Referer` = "http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/AJDocumentation.jsp?CndWAVE=-1",
            `Cookie` = cookie),
        body = post_data,
        encode = "form")

    location <- headers(response)$location
    location
}

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
if(length(args) == 0) {
    print("No file id specified. Use './script.r ####'.")
    quit("no")
}

fileId <- args[1]

# DOID=3843 : WVS_EVS_Integrated_Dictionary_Codebook v_2014_09_22 (Excel)
# DOID=3844 : WVS_Values Surveys Integrated Dictionary_TimeSeries_v_2014-04-25 (Excel)
# DOID=3725 : WVS_Longitudinal_1981-2014_rdata_v_2015_04_18
# DOID=3996 : WVS_Longitudinal_1981-2014_sas_v_2015_04_18
# DOID=3723 : WVS_Longitudinal_1981-2014_spss_v_2015_04_18
# DOID=3724 : WVS_Longitudinal_1981-2014_stata_dta_v_2015_04_18

getFileById(fileId)
```

Comment: Well, you did it - this time. For any other case - and every time anything changes at the site - this'll need doing all over again, and it'll be the same kind of challenge - back to the drawing board each time. This really is a task for a headless browser.
P.S. I now ironically see this in the side panel: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/144155/giving-malicious-crawlers-and-scripts-a-hard-time

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev You are opening a big subject about security here. The OPs question is about a specific web application and for some specific files. Of course, when the application gets upgraded with a strongest security pattern, this fetch code will break. The developers could have used even a captcha service to protect their forms from bots scraping like this one here. I just did the reversing of the HTTP requests to find out what it has to be sent to the server in order to return back the wanted result, which is the `302` response with the file it requests. This is what the OP is seeking for.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I wonder how a *headless browser* can successfully continue fetching such a request if it changes its pattern and even if the developers add protections like captcha. I don’t think that’s possible, but can you please provide some resources with such examples and how a *headless browser* can continue and successfully return the wanted result after a security method has totally or partially changed? I don’t know much about *headless browser* and I’d like to dig more into this subject.

Comment: I'm not saying a headless browser would automagically adapt to changes. I'm saying it will be much easier to adapt to them because you don't need to emulate Javascript logic and can copy all the needed xpaths right from a normal browser. Of course, your solution is just fine as a one-off task - or if changes are presumed to be rare and/or effort to detect and keep up with them tolerable.

Comment: So, a *headless browser* does something like parsing the responses javascript dom manipulation and `XMLHttpRequest`  calls for each HTTP response body and then it has a document result with all the javascript driven changes and additional calls, am I right?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I see you got a point. By using a *headless browser*, it will be most likely that the script will continue to work after some changes/additions. For example, developers add calls to more validation requests. This code here will fail. But with a *headless browser* it will execute everything according to the source and the script will continue to work! I wasn't so much into *headless browsers* even if I knew a few things about them. I will try to work for a *headless browser* solution for this problem here and I'll get back with an update!

Comment: It's also about the ease. I managed to quickly put together a selenium script to control a browser to get that URL. But there was no way I could manage to get it with curl. There was an iframe, then after you click the link, a nested iframe, for which the source was added with js. Then, there was the action of the form, also added with js. Then an intermediate jsp page, that used the ipinfo.io. I have to praise your achievement, @ChristosLytras. +1

Comment: hi, thanks for making this possible  https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/issues/130  sorry for not reviewing your work in time to award the first bounty, i'll give you the 300+ one.  thanks very very much

Comment: @AnthonyDamico you're welcome. Thank you for the extra bounty you offering. I really enjoy reversing and solving that kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the source of the underlying `httr::request_perform`](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/8fa4a71c84442447e1ef7a2d2d816696e2455021/R/request.R#L156), the object you get from `VERB()` looks like this:

```
res <- response(
  url = resp$url,
  status_code = resp$status_code,
  headers = headers,
  all_headers = all_headers,
  cookies = curl::handle_cookies(handle),
  content = resp$content,
  date = date,
  times = resp$times,
  request = req,
  handle = handle
)
```

So, you're interested in its `headers` or `all_headers` ([`response` is but a structure](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/8fa4a71c84442447e1ef7a2d2d816696e2455021/R/response.r#L22)). If a redirect was involved, `all_headers` will have multiple sets of headers as returned by [`curl::parse_headers()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/curl.pdf), `headers` are always the final set.

Comment: hi, sorry, i am downvoting because the objects `a$headers` and `a$all_headers` from my example in the question do not solve the stated problem

Comment: @AnthonyDamico the stated problem is "Programmatically scrape a response header within R", and it does that. If the real problem is "scrape a specific page for you" (i.e. determine which set of requests is needed to programmatically get to the file on that specific page), that's a completely different problem from the one stated.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico, I personally think that down votes are being used lightly very often in SO. You posted a question, a person made an effort to help. If you simply explain in a comment why that answer didn't solve the problem, most of the time, you will just get more help. You see how this could be taken as a lack of respect for the effort that was put into trying to help out.

Comment: @IvanChaer I personally think that on the contrary, the system discourages their use where they are due (in poor answer magnets) too much, so I don't hold any grudges here. The hover text on the downvote reads: "this answer is not useful". If my answer has been useless to a member of the target audience, that's neither good nor bad, that's a fact of life. If it's really as good as I've written it to be, it'll get upvotes eventually - the question title is Google-friendly, and the answer addresses exactly what it says.

Comment: @IvanChaer  As for your "lack of respect" assumption... don't you think that if system designers felt the same, they wouldn't have introduced downvotes in the first place?

Comment: When there is more than one question, sure, to differentiate. Judiciously, I think, as it can sometimes attract negativity. Apparently wasn't the case. ;)